# how to find accurate edges of the image?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, canny-operator

[image]

The above image is my output

i am using opencv edge dection c++ code,as written below

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_test_getPoints
(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jobject bitmap)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "Scaning getPoints");
    int ret;
    AndroidBitmapInfo info;
    void* pixels = 0;

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME,"AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return 0;
    }

    if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 )
    {       __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME,"Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888!");
        return 0;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME,"AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    Mat mbgra(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
 =========================================  
  vector<Point> img_pts = getPoints(mbgra);
  =====================================  
    jfloatArray jArray = env->NewFloatArray(8);

    if (jArray != NULL)
    {
        jfloat *ptr = env->GetFloatArrayElements(jArray, NULL);

        for (int i=0,j=i+4; j<8; i++,j++)
        {
            ptr[i] = img_pts[i].x;
            ptr[j] = img_pts[i].y;
        }
        env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(jArray, ptr, NULL);
    }
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
    return jArray;
}


vector<Point> getPoints(Mat image)
{
    int width = image.size().width;
    int height = image.size().height;
    Mat image_proc = image.clone();
    vector<vector<Point> > squares;
   Mat blurred(image_proc);
    medianBlur(image_proc, blurred, 9);
     Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
     for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
               const int threshold_level = 2;
        for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
        {
          if (l == 0)
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); //
              dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
            }
           findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
           vector<Point> approx;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
               approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);
               if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;
                    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }

        double largest_area = -1;
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<squares.size();i++)
        {
            double a =contourArea(squares[i],false);
            if(a>largest_area)
            {
                largest_area = a;
                largest_contour_index = i;
            }
        }

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "Scaning size() %d",squares.size());
        vector<Point> points;
        if(squares.size() > 0)
        {
            points = squares[largest_contour_index];
        }
        else
        {
            points.push_back(Point(0, 0));
            points.push_back(Point(width, 0));
            points.push_back(Point(0, height));
            points.push_back(Point(width, height));
        }

        return points;
    }
}
```

[image]

How to find accurate edges as per above screen shoot.

i am new for opencv can any one guide me,thanks for response.

**The ouput image**
 **required output**

Comment: Post your original image, too.

Comment: well the main problem here is that the color of the object and the color of the background are very similar. There are other constraint that may help? For example, you expect the object to be always a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, am expecting the object to be always a rectangle, how to achive this?and how to differ background and object.